# Actions on application startup

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'd like that each time my app starts up (possibly even when it's restored from background) it makes an action (for example `TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];`).
I'd also like that this action (on startup) can be disabled by a switch in the setting bundle of the app. What should I do? Thanks for your attention.

p.s. I apologize if I used incorrect words.. I'm a beginner :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several methods which you can implement in your application delegate which are available in the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol.

When your app is first launched `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is called.

When your app is restored from the background `applicationWillEnterForeground` is called.

A switch which you add to your setting bundle will have a key, which is an `NSString`, associated with it. A switch stores a boolean value encoded as an `NSNumber` in the standard `NSUserDefaults` under that key. You can read the value of the boolean from the standard user defaults and use it to determine whether to perform the action.

Apples documentation on how to add a settings bundle is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH6-SW5).
In your settings bundle you'll need a toggle switch. The key that you will look up in the standard user defaults is specified by the `Key` field. The default value for your toggle switch is specified by the `DefaultValue` field. [See here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Articles/PSToggleSwitchSpecifier.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007012-SW1)

Here is what you need to do in your `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method

```
static NSString *const kTakeActionOnLaunchSettingKey = @"Key";

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching
{
  NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  BOOL doTakeActionOnLaunch = [userDefaults boolForKey:kTakeActionOnLaunchSettingKey];
  if (doTakeActionOnLaunch) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialise it in voidDidLoad {} method. For disabling it you can use switch from object libary

Answer (score 1):

It's easy and I used it to make a cool transition from the splash screen to the home page.
You need to put your code inside the AppDelegate m file.

use

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

to run code at startup.

use the following methods to manage the Backgroud <-> Foreground transitions:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application 
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application 
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application 
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Hope this helps you.